# How to execute the sensor logs example of Mongo-Hadoop Connector?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, jar

I want to combine MongoDB with Hadoop. What I found is [Mongo-Hadoop Connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/README.md#supported-distributions-of-hadoop). However I could not find complete document about this example.

There are four files in `mongo-hadoop/examples/sensors`, `build`, `run_job.sh`, `src`, `testdata_generator.js`, respectively. I imported data to MongoDB by using `testdata_generator.js`, and the dbs is `demo`. When I try to run `run_job.sh`, there has an exception:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: demo
false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -D
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

**run_job.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh


mongo demo --eval "db.logs_aggregate.drop()"
#Set your HADOOP_HOME directory here.
#export HADOOP_HOME="/Users/mike/hadoop/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0" 
export HADOOP_HOME="/home/hduser/hadoop"

#FIRST PASS - map all the devices into an output collection
declare -a job1_args
job1_args=("jar" "`pwd`/build/libs/sensors-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-hadoop_2.2.jar")
#job1_args=(${job1_args[@]} "com.mongodb.hadoop.examples.sensors.Devices")
job1_args=(${job1_args[@]} "-D" "mongo.job.input.format=com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat")
job1_args=(${job1_args[@]} "-D" "mongo.input.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/demo.devices")
job1_args=(${job1_args[@]} "-D" "mongo.job.mapper=com.mongodb.hadoop.examples.sensors.DeviceMapper")
job1_args=(${job1_args[@]} "-D" "mongo.job.reducer=com.mongodb.hadoop.examples.sensors.DeviceReducer")

job1_args=(${job1_args[@]} "-D" "mongo.job.output.key=org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
job1_args=(${job1_args[@]} "-D" "mongo.job.output.value=org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")

job1_args=(${job1_args[@]} "-D" "mongo.output.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/demo.logs_aggregate")
job1_args=(${job1_args[@]} "-D" "mongo.job.output.format=com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat")
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop "${job1_args[@]}" "$1"
```

I can run basic Map/Reduce example in my computer, but this problem bothers me many days...

***New edited Contents:***

I could run this this example by below steps:

1. Compile `Devices.java`, `DeviceMapper.java`, `DeviceReducer.java`,
   and `SensorDataGenerator.java` to .class; The command is **`javac -classpath [library
   files] -d [folders] Devices.java DeviceMapper.java
   DeviceReducer.java SensorDataGenerator.java`**
2. Compile .class files to .jar; The command is **`jar -cvf [jar file name] -C [path]`**
3. Execute the hadoop; The command is hadoop **`jar [jar file name] [class name]`**

But I don't know why I could not execute the `run_job.sh` successfully.

Devices.java which is the main java file in this examples:

```
public class Devices extends MongoTool {

    public Devices() throws UnknownHostException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        MongoConfig config = new MongoConfig(conf);
        setConf(conf);

        config.setInputFormat(MongoInputFormat.class);
        config.setInputURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/demo.devices");
        config.setOutputFormat(MongoOutputFormat.class);
        config.setOutputURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/demo.logs_aggregate");

        config.setMapper(DeviceMapper.class);
        config.setReducer(DeviceReducer.class);
        config.setMapperOutputKey(Text.class);
        config.setMapperOutputValue(Text.class);
        config.setOutputKey(IntWritable.class);
        config.setOutputValue(BSONWritable.class);

        new SensorDataGenerator().run();
    }
    public static void main(final String[] pArgs) throws Exception {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new Devices(), pArgs));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run it using gradle.  those bash scripts are a bit outdated and should be removed:

./gradlew sensorData